# Integrating $\cosh^{-3}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can someone solve the following please:
$\int{\cosh^{-3}{x}}$?

Comment: https://wolframalpha.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Write the differential as $$\cosh^{-4}x\cosh x\,\mathrm dx=\cosh^{-4}x\,\mathrm d(\sinh x)=\frac{\mathrm d(\sinh x)}{(1+\sinh^2x)^2},$$ and by making the obvious substitution, you have a rational function as integrand, which you can do by the usual route -- partial fractions et. al.